# Vamos medir os esforços da comunidade usando métricas específicas

Tags: debate

Muito obrigado a [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) pela tradução.

---

[O objetivo da nossa comunidade](/help/manifesto) é criar um mundo no qual, para qualquer mecanismo de busca, os resultados mostrem um link para uma resposta detalhada em português.

Para que este mundo se torne realidade, juntos criamos uma base de conhecimento gratuita em português. O caminho para atingir este objetivo é duro e tortuoso; há grande chance de se perder. Eu acredito que precisamos de um ponto de referência que nos ajude a não desviar do caminho certo.

> Vamos pensar, quais métricas da comunidade podem nos guiar em direção ao nosso objetivo?

[image]

#### O que deve ser levado em conta ao escolher as métricas

Podemos usar quaisquer dados disponíveis para as métricas, não precisamos nos limitar às já existentes. Por outro lado, vale mencionar:

- *Quanto menos métricas usarmos, melhor*. A melhor opção seria criar uma única métrica para acompanhar o progresso geral. Por outro lado, o sistema possui vários aspectos importantes que são difíceis de se medir juntos.
- *Métricas devem ser interpretáveis*. O objetivo destas métricas é mostrar, de maneira simples, como nossos esforços estão trazendo alguma mudança: o que está indo bem e no que a comunidade deveria prestar mais atenção. Quanto mais fácil a associação entre a avaliação numérica de um processo da comunidade e a necessidade de agir para melhorá-lo, melhor.
- *Métricas devem ser universais*. Seria ótimo poder olhar a mesma métrica em sites diferentes para entender se nossas iniciativas estão funcionando ou se deveriam ser melhoradas.

#### Principais métricas: Comunidade, Qualidade, Quantidade

Para ter uma ideia do *status* da comunidade como um todo, eu vejo três áreas onde podemos usar métricas específicas:

1. *Comunidade*. O quão confortáveis estão os usuários da comunidade? Eles são ativos no site (perguntam e respondem, votam, etc)? Eles querem convidar os amigos? Estes amigos querem se juntar à comunidade?
2. *Qualidade*. O quão útil e interessante é o conhecimento que criamos, para os usuários e os desenvolvedores falantes de português em geral?
3. *Quantidade*. O quão rápido a base de conhecimento está crescendo? Quais perguntas que são necessárias e não estão presentes na base de conhecimento?

#### Quais métricas você quer ver?

Por favor compartilhe as métricas que você gostaria de usar para acompanhar o progresso da comunidade. Como calculá-las? Que dados seriam usados para medi-las?

Por favor coloque **apenas uma métrica por resposta** para evitar confusão. Tentarei implementar as melhores propostas para cada uma das seções (comunidade, qualidade, quantidade) e disponibilizá-las para todos.

Comment: "*é criar um mundo no qual, para qualquer mecanismo de busca, os resultados mostrem um link para uma resposta detalhada*", exceto a própria busca do site, que dificilmente retorna aquilo que você deseja :D

Comment: A imagem do farol é suposto ter algum significado profundo que eu não atingi ?

Comment: @Isac "...quais métricas da comunidade podem nos **guiar** em direção ao nosso objetivo"

Comment: @Isac entenda que um farol tem dispositivos trabalhando 24h/dia para sinalizar o caminho mais seguro, além de se comunicar com os navegantes (bidirecionalmente), em suma, trabalha dando apoio, informações e as direções devidas. Mas se resume na atividade aparentemente solitária e imóvel. Acho q tem significado que cada um pode entender contemplando as próprias atribuições/atividades do farol.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe Essa sua explicação foi boa :)